# got error message when i trying to use php, thrift and cassandra

Tags: php, cassandra, thrift

i try to write a class to connect to cassandra using php
but i have an error!!

Fatal error: Class 'Thrift\Exception\TException' not found in /usr/share/php/Thrift/packages/cassandra/Types.php on line 709

everybody can help me?

tnx

Comment: install thrift properly?

Comment: @MarcB,i using this instruction to install thrift. https://pressflow.atlassian.net/wiki/display/PF/Using+Cassandra+with+PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly suggest using a higher level client instead of the raw machine-generated interface created by Thrift.  For example, [phpcassa](https://github.com/thobbs/phpcassa) wraps the Thrift code to create a much friendlier interface.

Comment: Absolutely agree. Programmng the raw Cassandra API requires a certain level of knowledge, plus the existing clients provide a more higher-level abstraction, to some extent.